# A book containing brief biographies of famous Indian mathematicians

Tags: book-recommendation, math-history

I want to read about famous Indian mathematicians (for example, Ramanujan, Aryabhatta, etc.), their biographies and their research contributions.

Please suggest me books which include brief introductions to their life and work.

To clarify, I am looking for brief introductions to most of the famous Indian mathematicians in one book. I am not interested in books focusing on one mathematician only (I want a reference book so that I can encourage my students to doing Mathematics).

Comment: Maybe useful : [History of Hindu Mathematics: A Source Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Hindu_Mathematics:_A_Source_Book) (1930).

Comment: The question is now open again. One reason why it might have been closed is that in your original version your intent was less clear and the question could seem rather broad. Now, that the type of book got narrowed down by your comments that where integrated into the post by edits this is no longer the case.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some works which deal with ancient Indian mathematics:

1. [*Mathematics in India*, Kim Plofker](https://www.amazon.in/Mathematics-India-Kim-Plofker/dp/0691120676). I believe this book is now considered the standard text on the subject. The author is an American historian of mathematics, and she specializes in Indian mathematics.
2. [*Ancient Leaps into Mathematics*, B.S. Yadav and Man Mohan (eds.)](https://www.amazon.in/Ancient-Indian-Leaps-into-Mathematics-ebook/dp/B008BBJEGG/ref=tmm_kin_swatch_0?_encoding=UTF8&qid=1548942055&sr=1-1). This book contains a collection of articles by various authors on the mathematics of ancient India. The preface mentions several related works (including *History of Hindu Mathematics: A Source Book* mentioned by @MauroALLEGRANZA in the comments), which can also be of interest to you.
3. [*Studies in the History of Indian Mathematics*, C.S. Seshadri (ed.)](http://www.hindbook.com/index.php/studies-in-the-history-of-indian-mathematics). This volume is a part of the *Culture and History of Mathematics* series of Hindustan Book Agency. The articles cover a large part of the history of Indian mathematics and astronomy.
4. [*Contributions to the History of Indian Mathematics*, Emch, Sridharan & Srinivas (eds.)](http://www.hindbook.com/index.php/contributions-to-the-history-of-indian-mathematics). At the first Joint India-AMS meeting in Mathematics held in Bangalore in December 2003, two sessions on the theme of "History of Indian Mathematics" were held. The lectures delivered there were compiled and the outcome was this volume.